# How can I change the image when hovering over a link?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Greetings how to implement this menu. Its trick is that when the mouse is on the link of a certain product, this product is displayed above.

My attempts to implement this functionality:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $img = $('.card-img-top'),
    dsrc = $img.attr('src');
  $('.list-group li a').hover(function() {
    var $this = $(this).addClass('hover');
    $img.attr('src', $this.data('image'));
  }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
    $img.attr('src', dsrc);
  });
});
```

```css
.card {
  border: none;
  margin: 0px 30px 0px 0px;
}

.card-img-top {
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 230px;
  width: 370px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

.card-block {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.link a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #212529;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="py-4">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row hidden-md-up">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://www.koemmerling.com/cms16/files/Fenster-Haustueren-Verteiler.jpg?h=246" class="card-img-top" id="first">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h5 class="card-title fw-bold">Оконные и дверные системы</h5><br>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
              <li class="list-group-item link"><a id="1" href="#" data-image="https://www.koemmerling.com/cms16/files/38_System-88-MD-Standard_weiss_web.jpg?h=246"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i> 88 мм</a></li>
              <li class="list-group-item link"><a id="2" href="#" data-image="https://www.koemmerling.com/cms16/files/5_System-76-AD-Standard_weiss_web.jpg?h=246"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i> 76 мм</a></li>
              <li class="list-group-item link"><a id="3" href="#" data-image="https://www.koemmerling.com/cms16/files/1_System-70-AD-Standard_weiss_web.jpg?h=246"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i> 70 мм</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://www.koemmerling.com/cms16/files/KOEMMERLING-PremiPlan-Verteiler-Produkte.jpg?h=246" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h5 class="card-title fw-bold">Пороговые системы</h5><br>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
              <li class="list-group-item link"><a id="1" href="#" data-image="/38_System-88-MD-Standard_weiss_web.jpg"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i> 88 мм</a></li>
              <li class="list-group-item link"><a id="2" href="#" data-image="/5_System-76-AD-Standard_weiss_web.jpg"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i> 76 мм</a></li>
              <li class="list-group-item link"><a id="3" href="#" data-image="/1_System-70-AD-Standard_weiss_web.jpg"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i> 70 мм</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://www.koemmerling.com/cms16/files/Schiebesysteme-Verteiler.jpg?h=246" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h5 class="card-title fw-bold">Раздвижные системы</h5><br>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
              <li class="list-group-item link"><a id="1" href="#" data-image="/38_System-88-MD-Standard_weiss_web.jpg"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i> 88 мм</a></li>
              <li class="list-group-item link"><a id="2" href="#" data-image="/5_System-76-AD-Standard_weiss_web.jpg"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i> 76 мм</a></li>
              <li class="list-group-item link"><a id="3" href="#" data-image="/1_System-70-AD-Standard_weiss_web.jpg"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i> 70 мм</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I would be extremely grateful if anyone could help me figure out how to do this.

[image]

```
<div class="card">
          <img src="/Schiebesysteme-Verteiler.jpeg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h5 class="card-title fw-bold">Раздвижные системы</h5><br>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
              <li class="list-group-item link"><a id="1" href="#" data-image="/38_System-88-MD-Standard_weiss_web.jpg"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i> 88 мм</a></li>
              <li class="list-group-item link"><a id="2" href="#" data-image="/5_System-76-AD-Standard_weiss_web.jpg"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i> 76 мм</a></li>
              <li class="list-group-item link"><a id="3" href="#" data-image="/1_System-70-AD-Standard_weiss_web.jpg"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i> 70 мм</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$img` is all the top images. You should just change the image in the same `.card` group.

You can't use a global variable for the previous image, since it's different for each image. Save it in another `data()` variable.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.list-group li a').hover(function() {
  console.log("hover");
    var $this = $(this).addClass('hover');
    var $img = $this.closest(".card").find(".card-img-top");
    $img.data("orig-src", $img.attr("src"));
    $img.attr('src', $this.data('image'));
  }, function() {
  console.log("remove");
    var $this = $(this).removeClass('hover');
    var $img = $this.closest(".card").find(".card-img-top");
    $img.attr('src', $img.data("orig-src"));
  });
});
```

```css
.card {
  border: none;
  margin: 0px 30px 0px 0px;
}

.card-img-top {
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 230px;
  width: 370px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

.card-block {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.link a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #212529;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="py-4">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row hidden-md-up">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://www.koemmerling.com/cms16/files/Fenster-Haustueren-Verteiler.jpg?h=246" class="card-img-top" id="first">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h5 class="card-title fw-bold">Оконные и дверные системы</h5><br>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
              <li class="list-group-item link"><a id="1" href="#" data-image="https://www.koemmerling.com/cms16/files/38_System-88-MD-Standard_weiss_web.jpg?h=246"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i> 88 мм</a></li>
              <li class="list-group-item link"><a id="2" href="#" data-image="https://www.koemmerling.com/cms16/files/5_System-76-AD-Standard_weiss_web.jpg?h=246"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i> 76 мм</a></li>
              <li class="list-group-item link"><a id="3" href="#" data-image="https://www.koemmerling.com/cms16/files/1_System-70-AD-Standard_weiss_web.jpg?h=246"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i> 70 мм</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://www.koemmerling.com/cms16/files/KOEMMERLING-PremiPlan-Verteiler-Produkte.jpg?h=246" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h5 class="card-title fw-bold">Пороговые системы</h5><br>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
              <li class="list-group-item link"><a id="1" href="#" data-image="/38_System-88-MD-Standard_weiss_web.jpg"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i> 88 мм</a></li>
              <li class="list-group-item link"><a id="2" href="#" data-image="/5_System-76-AD-Standard_weiss_web.jpg"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i> 76 мм</a></li>
              <li class="list-group-item link"><a id="3" href="#" data-image="/1_System-70-AD-Standard_weiss_web.jpg"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i> 70 мм</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://www.koemmerling.com/cms16/files/Schiebesysteme-Verteiler.jpg?h=246" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h5 class="card-title fw-bold">Раздвижные системы</h5><br>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
              <li class="list-group-item link"><a id="1" href="#" data-image="/38_System-88-MD-Standard_weiss_web.jpg"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i> 88 мм</a></li>
              <li class="list-group-item link"><a id="2" href="#" data-image="/5_System-76-AD-Standard_weiss_web.jpg"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i> 76 мм</a></li>
              <li class="list-group-item link"><a id="3" href="#" data-image="/1_System-70-AD-Standard_weiss_web.jpg"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i> 70 мм</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` refer to the target element (the link). You want to get from there to the correct image, so you need to go up to the closest common parent, then find the image.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.list-group li a').hover(function() {
    var $this = $(this).addClass('hover');
    var $img = $(this).closest(".card").find('.card-img-top');
    $img.attr('src', $this.data('image'));
  }, function() {
    // to revert use same logic, only save the value as attribute `data-old-src` or something
  });
});
```